# Help with Voting Table Schema Idea

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a voting table and maximize performance.  Since a vote can only be UP or DOWN, I'm thinking of using `bit` where `1 = up` and `0 = down` is this unintuitive? is there a better way?

```
UserVotes (3 way primary key between all three tables)
+----------+----------+-------------+
|  UserID  |  IsUp    | CommentID   |
+----------+----------+-------------+
|    1     |  1       |  99         |
|    2     |  0       |  99         |
```

etc.

The updates will happen when a user clicks a vote up or a vote down button

```
If VoteUpButtonClicked Then
    VoteService.Add(userID,True, CommentID)
End If

If VoteDownButtonClicked Then
     VoteService.Add(userID, False, CommentID)
End If
```

Then the calls will be "count"

```
Dim TotalUpVotes = VoteServce.QueryVotes().Where(Function(v) v.IsUp And v.CommentID = CommentID).Count
Dim TotalDownVotes = VoteService.QueryVotes().Where(Function(v) Not v.IsUp And v.CommentID = CommentID).Count
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and Linq to SQL.

And yes, I would like to allow users to delete a vote.

Comment: How will you use the table? How many updates per second? How many queries per second? What sort of queries?

Comment: Also, what database and version?

Comment: can users remove their votes?

Comment: edited the question to answer your follow-ups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have the voting table keep a live sum of the votes:

UpVote int
DownVote int

+1 to the applicable column when a user vote.

Store the votes in a log table

UserID
CommentID
IsUp (bit)

If a user deletes his vote, you can interrogate IsUp and -1 on either UpVote or DownVote.

Comment: This might not be a bad idea to complement @hunter's answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
UserId (int) PK
CommentId (int) PK
Vote (tinyint) (1 or -1)
Voted (Date)
```

Then you can simply sum the values

Comment: Since this is one of my most frequent hit tables, I'm trying to design with performance in mind. Will the `tinyint / sum` perform equally as well as `bit / count`?

Comment: @rockinthesixstring if you use LINQPad or watch the query come through in SQL Profiler you will see that using the LINQ to SQL Query using the `Sum()` method, the resulting query will be something like `SELECT SUM(Vote) FROM...`

Comment: I used LinqPad to see what you mean. `Count(*)` is more overhead than `Sum(vote)`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are the one that will be wrapping the table in logic to accomplish the requirements of your project, I would assume it is you that needs to answer the question of whether or not it is intuitive.  It needs to be intuitive to you.